# Sintaxe Árvores Binárias

Tags: árvore-binária

Boa tarde Desenvolvedores.

Estou estudando Estruturas de Dados na faculdade, e com a falta de zelo pelo material apresentado por parte da instituição, estou pesquisando por conta própria na internet, e por este motivo cá estou.

Hoje cheguei no módulo de **árvores binárias**, e ao realizar pesquisas afim de entender mais sobre, me deparei com este vídeo: [Link para o mesmo.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PgZflufXGUU&t=179s)
Na tutoria ele cita que existem duas entidades principais, os **nós** e **arcos**, por meio da lógica, ao citar estes elementos em minha mente foi criada a referência : Círculos = Arcos , Traços= Nós.
Em seguida ele cita que os nós da esquerda e direita são filhos, e que o nó pai é o primeiro, que deu origem a eles.

E foi com base nesta fala meu cérebro veio a cair em discórdia, pelo simples fato de que assumi que os círculos seriam Arcos e Nós as linhas. Eu acho que já deu para entenderem a minha dúvida, e espero que açguém possa a me ajudar a sanar a mesma, agradeço de ante-mão.

**Obrigado.**

Comment: Nós = Círculos, Linhas = Arcos. As linhas é que fazem o relacionamento entre os nós.

Comment: @GiulianaBezerra - Certo então, eu estava mofando com esta dúvida.